# Нужна ли запятая перед "и?"

Tags: запятые, союзы, и

"В покои пришла Марья, и служанки засуетились." нужна ли тут запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужна. ССП.

Две основы:

1. Марья пришла.
2. Служанки засуетились.

Куда пришла М., не важно: "покои" не работают общим для двух предложений словом; суета служанок связана с появлением М.